# lambda calling another external lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I can easily do this:

```
auto f = []()->int { return 4; };
auto g = [f]()->int { return f(); });
int i = g();
```

Nevertheless, I cannot do this:

```
int (*f)() = []()->int { return 4; };
int (*g)() = [f]()->int { return f(); });
int i = g();
```

Why I got such message in MSVC?

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'ClassName::functionName::< lambda_b2eebcdf2b88a20d8b40b0a03c412089>' to 'int (__cdecl *)(void)'
```

This occurs on line:

```
int (*g)() = [f]()->int { return f(); });
```

How to do this properly?

Comment: If this is at namespace scope, you can just omit the `f` from the capture list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int (*f)() = []()->int { return 4; };
```

is still fine because lambdas with empty capture lists implicitly convert to matching function pointers.

This (crucial) condition is however not met in the second line:

```
int (*g)() = [f]()->int { return f(); });
              ^
```

Thus the conversion fails.

If you want to store a lambda that captures something, you either need an [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), or deduce the type with `auto` as you did before; whatever fits your usecase. Function pointers simply cannot do that (in C++11, for the future, see [Yakk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39731784/3002139)).

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can wait for C++17.

```
template<auto F>
struct function_ptr;
template<class R, class...Args, R(*F)(Args...)>
struct function_ptr<F> {
  using signature = R(Args...);
  constexpr R operator()(Args...args)const {
    return F(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  constexpr operator signature*() const { return F; }
  constexpr signature* operator+() const { return F; }
};
```

now:

```
constexpr auto f_ = []()->int { return 4; };
function_ptr<+f_> f;
```

generates a function-pointer like `f`.

```
template<class T>struct tag_t {};

template<class F, class...Fs, class R, class...Args>
constexpr auto chain_functions(tag_t<R(Args...)>) {
  constexpr r = [](Args...args)->R{
    return F{}( Fs{}..., std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  };
  return function_ptr<+r>{};
}
```

lets us chain function pointers.

```
constexpr auto f_ = []()->int { return 4; };
function_ptr<+f_> f0;
constexpr auto g_ = [](int(*f)())->int { return f(); });
function_ptr<+g_> g_raw;
auto g0 = chain_functions< function_ptr<+g_>, function_ptr<+f_> >( tag_t<int()>{} );
```

now `g` is a `function_ptr`.

```
int(*g)() = g0;
```

should hopefully compile and work.  (Not tested, I don't have access to a sufficiently C++17 compiler).

Still a bit obtuse, and definitely not tested.  Basically `function_ptr` is intended to create a *type* that carries a compile-time function pointer.  C++17 provides us with `constexpr` lambdas, including the ability to get the function pointer out of them in a `constexpr` context.

We can then compose these function pointer types to generate a new function pointer type.